# Use of LIKE vs AS

Tags: grammar

I would let he clever ones learn Latin ***as*** an honour.
Why the writer used **as** before phrase although ***like*** is most often seen before phrase and ***as*** is mostly seen before clause

Comment: As conjunctions, "as" and "like" are used with the same meaning.  As prepositions, they have very different meanings.

Answer (score 4):

In the example you give the author is saying that learning Latin is assigned the status of an honour, it is considered to be an honour. For this purpose, using **as** as a preposition is appropriate

> ... learn Latin as an honour

the (Merriam-Webster) dictionary definition of **as** includes **... how a thing is thought of ...**.

**like** when used as a preposition is better used when we want to indicate a descriptive similarity, a simile

> he ran like a greyhound

There are other meanings of both **like** and **as**, so I'm not sure you should pay too much attention to statistics of their respective usages.

Comment: "using 'as' as a preposition' --- I see what you did there!

Comment: I thought that it's the use of  the preposition "like" like it were a conjunction, even if it is controversial, may be regarded as commonly accepted. Never have heard of using the conjunction "as" as if it were a preposition. I'm sort of puzzled.

Comment: Also, I've always thought that most of the confusion in the use of "like" or "as" is basically caused by a lack of attention to the words' roles, "like" being a preposition and "so" —  a conjunction.

Comment: @Rompey *as* has three uses in all the dictionaries I've looked at: adverb, conjunction or preposition. Must admit it's not the sort of distinction I've previously been aware of, but that's part of the charm of researching these answers.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now -- enjoying this charm.